# Does C++ for Arduino follow the standard?

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, arduino-c++, freestanding

C++ programs on the Arduino platform do not have a `main()` function like on other platforms; instead, it must have two functions named `setup()` and `loop()`. But  according to C++ standard - all C++ programs must have a `main()` function.

So, does such C++ code conform to the standard? Do C++ compilers/linkers/loaders on Arduino conform to the standard?

Comment: It _does_ have a `main` function, its just not in your code.

Comment: The syntactic elements do, the standard library not.

Comment: Does it maybe have an 'in-built' (and hidden) `main` function that calls `setup` and `loop`?

Comment: You don't have to have `main()` in every compilation unit.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Please see the answer. It may not be non-compliant.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, my understanding is that in freestanding mode, what libraries are provided is implementation defined, so the lack of a standard library does not rule out compliance: https://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance.general#7

Answer (score 7):

The C++ standard provides for two execution environments: freestanding and hosted. Most folks here run in a hosted environment, where your program starts in`main()`. Embedded systems run in a freestanding environment, where program startup is through an implementation-defined mechanism. Compilers for a freestanding environment are allowed to leave out some parts of the standard library. For more details, [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/freestanding).

So, `setup()` and `loop()` are okay in a freestanding environment. No `main()` required. I don’t know if the library for Arduino meets the requirements in the standard.

In a hosted environment, there’s typically an operating system (the host) that lets you launch programs. C++ programs for such an environment must have `main()`. In a freestanding environment, the program typically starts when the device is turned on. That’s much closer to the metal, and the system is allowed to have its own requirements, in order simplify the boilerplate code that fires off the application.

Comment: Not worth me adding a new answer with the standard text if you want to include it in this: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.start.main#1.sentence-3

Comment: It provides no std. You can't even `new` an object. There are partial implementations available which you import by adding to your application source code.

Comment: Added a link to the standard text as well, hope that's ok.

Comment: @cigien — I rolled back your addition. That’s a small part of the standard”s wording about freestanding environments. It addresses `main()`, but not the library requirements.

Comment: That's fair. I still feel that the standard text about `main`, and the text about the library requirements should be added to the answer. Just linking to cppreference for a language-lawyer question doesn't feel right to me :p

Comment: @cigien — I don’t think it’s a language lawyer question. It’s more a question of basic knowledge. As the comments to the question suggest, most people aren’t aware of the existence of freestanding environments.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I agree with that reasoning. The question says, "does this code conform to the standard?" That alone qualifies it, I think. And the fact that people don't seem to have some basic knowledge is neither here nor there. Not to mention that what you consider basic knowledge might be an advanced concept for others ;)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux you can't `new` an object? That's not true at all. Am I missing something?

Comment: @rfb The last time I used the default Arduino C++ environment, you had to provide operator new yourself to get a new expression working. You couldn't `new` out-of-the-box.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OK fine. But this didn't apply to the versions at the date of your answer, forgive me.

Answer (score 5):

Just to have said it out loud here: there *is* a [main.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp), that looks roughly like this:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

int main(void) {
  init();
  setup();
  for (;;) {
    loop();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The Arduino IDE supplies it. The IDE also generates function prototypes if they aren't there already, and does some other things.

So, the absence of a `main()` in the visible code in the Arduino IDE doesn't mean it isn't there, or that it violates the standard.